# How many extra dimensions needed to model the Strong interaction with a Kaluza-Klein extended theory?

Tags: standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, spacetime-dimensions, kaluza-klein

The blog / video (See: https://backreaction.blogspot.com/2021/04/does-universe-have-higher-dimensions.html - Does the Universe have Higher Dimensions? Sabine Hossenfelder's blog) is discussing the history and popular concepts behind Kaluza-Klein approach and its extension to derive and model the other interactions. In that contact, Sabine mention R. Kerner's paper(1968) to extend Kaluza-Klein (to derive any Yang Mills field) and states that it would take +4 additional dimensions to make the strong interaction appear (+1 is the usual KK derivation of EM and +2 for the Weak interaction). Kerner paper or other detailed reviews and work on KK do not mention +4 for the strong interaction. Does anybody have a pointer or a derivation / justification for the +4 (vs. say +3) other than the fact (see below) that at least 7D compact dimensions are required for SM.

Would the dimension result change in a induced space time matter model where the dimensions are not compact (and I am not sure how fiber bundle models are adapted) and 4D spacetime is embedded?

References:
Kerner paper: Kerner R 1968, " Generalization of the Kaluza-Klein theory for an arbitrary non-abelian gauge group. " Ann. Inst. H Poincare' 9 143
Other somehow relevant papers:
David Bailint and Alex Love, (1987), “Kaluza-Klein theories”, Rep. Prog. Phys. 50 (1987) 1087-1170
https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03128
Frank Reifler and Randall Morris, "Conditions for exact equivalence of Kaluza-Klein and Yang-Mills theories"

Yes, it is related but not explicitly answered (IMHO) in [Does Kaluza-Klein theory successfully unify GR and EM? Why can't it be extended to the Standard Model gauge group?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27689/): I am after the explicit generation of the strong interaction. As note in that answer (and in reference above), for SM the minimum dimension is 7. Is it that reasoning that ends up with 4 (vs. 3) for the strong interaction or has an actual derivation been done somewhere.

Comment: The basic idea is you take the dimension of the gauge group then you can quotient out by a maximal subgroup. Note the the dimension of G=SU(3) is 8 not 3 (it has 8 generators). But then it has a maximal subgroup H=SU(2)xU(1) which has dimension 3+1=4. So the quotient G/H has dimension 8-4=4. That is not a complete explanation, but is that the sort of answer you are looking for, then maybe someone can expand on that as an answer.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of that (i.e. it's the reasoning of say the answer to "Does Kaluza-Klein theory successfully unify GR and EM? Why can't it be extended to the Standard Model gauge group?"). It's the fiber bundle reasoning. Thank you for answering and confirming that. It helps. Did anybody derive / publish that actual field formulation of the strong interaction resulting from KK?

Comment: So that paper you reference from 2016 has the title "The Standard Model in extra dimensions and its Kaluza-Klein effective Lagrangian" and does give the effective field formulation in great detail for all interactions. I didn't follow exactly what method they were using for compactification or how many dimensions they had.

Comment: Yes that paper offers a generic solution for SM but function of n extra dimensions. It does not seem to provide a prescription to determine valid n and it seems a different derivation and maybe solution from the Kerner approach.  So yes, maybe I should have been clearer and ask about the outcome of the Kerber recipe applied to QCD and in particular therefore for n=4.